# VyOS configuration qos by ip

Tags: vyos

I have a simple question, VyOS is a bit new to me.
I am trying to apply traffic shaper QOS. 
this configuration works but I would have to repeat it 80 times (class  20, 21, 22, 23....)

```
set traffic-policy shaper DOWNLOAD-POLICY class 20 bandwidth 35%
set traffic-policy shaper DOWNLOAD-POLICY class 20 ceiling 95%
set traffic-policy shaper DOWNLOAD-POLICY class 20 priority 2
set traffic-policy shaper DOWNLOAD-POLICY class 20 match COMPUTERS ip destination address 192.168.1.20/32
```

How would I do something like this

```
set traffic-policy shaper DOWNLOAD-POLICY class 20 match COMPUTERS ip destination address 192.168.1.20-192.168.1.80
```